# How do I put this sub query just as join?

Tags: join, subquery

```
select m.m_name, p.place_town
from musician m
inner join place p
    on m.born_in = p.place_no
where m.born_in = (select m.born_in from musician m where m.m_name = 'James First') and
    m.m_name != 'James First'
```

Comment: The subquery does not appear to be correlated, so it might be less bad than you think.

Comment: well still, is it possible do a self join to eliminate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the subquery with a self-join:

```
select m.m_name, p.place_town
from musician m
inner join place p
    on m.born_in = p.place_no
inner join
(
    select m.born_in
    from musician m
    where m.m_name = 'James First'
) t 
    on m.born_in = t.place_no
where m.m_name != 'James First'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. but a slight change on your query is giving me the right answer.                                                                                     select m.m_name, p.place_town
from musician m
inner join place p
    on m.born_in = p.place_no
inner join
(
    select m.born_in
    from musician m
    where m.m_name = 'James First'
) as t 
    on t.born_in = p.place_no
where m.m_name != 'James First'

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.m_name, p.place_town
```

from musician m
inner join place p
    on m.born_in = p.place_no
inner join
(
    select m.born_in
    from musician m
    where m.m_name = 'James First'
) as t 
    on t.born_in = p.place_no
where m.m_name != 'James First'